# Access a DataFrame element with Pandas, when we don't use the index

Tags: python, pandas

When we use the index to select a specific row, we can access an element with `.loc`, `.iloc`, etc.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["col1", "col2"], index=["aa", "bb"])
x = df.loc["aa", "col2"]
print(x, type(x))  # 2 <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

But when our `id` column is *not* the index, such as:

```
   id  col1  col2
0  aa     1     2
1  bb     3     4
```

**what is the natural Pandas way to access the element of column `col2` and of row of `id` equal to `aa`?**

This doesn't work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["aa", 1, 2], ["bb", 3, 4]], columns=["id", "col1", "col2"])
x = df[df["id"] == "aa"]["col2"]
print(x, type(x))
# 0    2
# Name: col2, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

because it outputs a `Series` and not a number as expected. Is there a more standard way than adding an extra `[0]`:

```
x = df[df["id"] == "aa"]["col2"][0]  # 2, as expected
```

?

---

TL;DR: Why is `df[df["id"] == "aa"]["col2"]` a `Series` and not an element?

Answer (score 1):

> what is the natural Pandas way to access the element of column col2 and of row of id equal to aa?

Unfortunately not exist, need convert `id` to `index` first for avoid one element `Series`, so need select by position `[0]`.

Comment: Thanks. If we don't want to change the `index`, for example because another column is used as an index, how do we do it?

Comment: @Basj - Not sure if understand, convert existing index to columns and then necessary column used for selecting to index. another way is use MultiIndex, but not sure if avoid one element Series

Comment: why is `df[df["id"] == "aa"]["col2"]` a `Series` and not an element?

Comment: @Basj - because [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) return Dataframe or Series, not scalar.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return a scalar after applying a boolean mask, you can use [**`pandas.Series.values`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) :

```
x = df.loc[df['id'] == 'aa', 'col2'].values[0]

print(x, type(x))
2 <class 'numpy.int64'> #output
```